# Quarkus cache return always the same value with different chache keys

Tags: caching, quarkus

I have use `@CacheResult` to store result of a computation in order to optimize subsequent requests with the same id.

I have implemented something like the following:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Processor {

    @CacheResult(cacheName = "process_result")
    public Result processs(@CacheKey String resourceId, ProcessParameters pParams) {
        Result = new Result(resourceId);
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I call with `resourceId` 123 for the first time (cache is empty) all work fine. When I make a call for the first time with `resourceId` 456 I get the result of 123 instead the expected result of 456.

The keys are different so I should have two different entries in the cache. I can't understand why it dosen't works.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducer and create an issue in our tracker here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues ? Thanks!

Comment: update to version 1.7.0-Final fix the problem

Comment: Perfect, we indeed fixed some cache key generation issue in 1.7.0.Final so that might be it!